# Google sign in not working after uploading application at play Store

Tags: android, google-signin

Google Sign in was working fine before uploading to play store, but after uploading the app to the store, google sign in is not working, and returning always false in handleSignInResult() method.

Below is the code that is used :

```
 try {
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                // .requestEmail()
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.server_client_id))
                .requestEmail()
                // .requestScopes(new Scope(Scopes.DRIVE_APPFOLDER))
                // .requestServerAuthCode(getString(R.string.server_client_id), false)
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
                .enableAutoManage(getActivity() /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .build();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        Log.e("IllegalStateException ", e.toString());
    }

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


    // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == RC_GET_TOKEN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        handleSignInResult(result);
    }


}
  private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
    Log.d(TAG, "handleSignInResult:" + result.isSuccess());
    if (result.isSuccess()) {
        // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
        GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
}
```

Comment: Is it possible you have tested with debug key and not with release key?

Comment: Api Key for release apk is different, so update your api key in google developer console

Comment: Ok. Thanks i did using release SHA1 Key.

Answer (score 1):

You have to update your Google Developer Console API.
inside credentals:

https://console.developers.google.com/apis/

If your application works in the debug. Add to your key the SHA for release key.