# Google sign-in will stop working after signing the app in Play Console

Tags: android, google-signin, google-one-tap

A lot of answers to the topic but the majority are relevant to Firebase and even if I tried with or without Firebase I received the same generic error `Exception com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: Developer console is not setup correctly.`.

The problem:

Using any build (debug, release) and while we have CI-CD to deploy and distribute the app via AppCenter everything works great in all environments (test, production), but, as soon as we release the app in Google Play Console or use the App Bundle Explorer in Play Console to upload the AAB and download the APK to test locally on a device, Google Sign-on doesn't work.

Now while banging my head after 2 weeks of research and trying to understand what that means I did the following.

- Reset the upload key in Google Play Console
- Reset the Google Play app signing key in Google Play Console
- Recreated the Android credentials in Google Cloud Console (with recreating the web client - even tried the Firebase auto-created one)
- Tried with a Firebase App
- Code from the latest documentation ([https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/android/overview](https://One%20tap%20Google%20Signin))
- Firebase YouTube videos ([https://youtu.be/zCIfBbm06QM?si=FlHtl7Hwk6xZc8KQ](https://Firebase%20Tutorial))
- The Android Kotlin codebase is structured using modules, moved the authentication module into the main module app (An attempt to exclude the package name being different in the module)
- Created a clean Android Kotlin project with just a Google Sign-in button (same error)
- Ensuring multiple times the web client OAuth Client ID is used (well, it would have a meaningful error if not anyway)
- I submitted the Google Could OAuth Screen Consent for approval and still pending. I don't believe this is an issue because we request sensitive scopes.

I have only one Google Cloud Android OAuth Client ID using the upload key SHA1 (I tried adding a second with the Google Play signing SHA1 but didn't really change anything). This is an attempt to fix the issue from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/41034093/122769.
I actually use the same SHA1 for debug and release. See sign-in report below. Another answer but again relevant to using Firebase (https://stackoverflow.com/a/68094280/122769).
I have a sense that I may be doing something wrong around needing to have different SHA1 for the builds; but not sure how to approach it (not sure how/where to add the SHA1 for release https://stackoverflow.com/a/39347133/122769)

`./gradlew signingReport`:

```
Variant: testRelease
Config: config
Store: some_path_to_store/release.jks
Alias: company
MD5: 57:MD5
SHA1: 99:SHA1
SHA-256: C3:SHA256
Valid until: Thursday, Month 9, 2045

Variant: prodRelease
Config: config
Store: some_path_to_store/release.jks
Alias: company
MD5: 57:MD5
SHA1: 99:SHA1
SHA-256: C3:SHA256
Valid until: Thursday, Month 9, 2045
```

The code:

```
package com.eight.app

import android.content.IntentSender
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResult
import androidx.activity.result.IntentSenderRequest
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegate
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.identity.BeginSignInRequest
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.identity.Identity
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.identity.SignInClient
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var errorText: TextView
    private lateinit var googleButton: TextView
    private lateinit var oneTapClient: SignInClient
    private lateinit var signInRequest: BeginSignInRequest
    private val activityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartIntentSenderForResult(), ::handleSignInResult)

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.a_start)
        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO)
        errorText = findViewById(R.id.errorText)
        googleButton = findViewById(R.id.googleButton)

        oneTapClient = Identity.getSignInClient(this)
        signInRequest = BeginSignInRequest.builder()
            .setPasswordRequestOptions(
                BeginSignInRequest.PasswordRequestOptions.builder()
                    .setSupported(true)
                    .build(),
            )
            .setGoogleIdTokenRequestOptions(
                BeginSignInRequest.GoogleIdTokenRequestOptions.builder()
                    .setSupported(true)
                    // Your server's client ID, not your Android client ID.
                    .setServerClientId(getString(R.string.your_web_client_id))
                    // Only show accounts previously used to sign in.
                    .setFilterByAuthorizedAccounts(false)
                    .build(),
            )
            // Automatically sign in when exactly one credential is retrieved.
            .setAutoSelectEnabled(true)
            .build()

        googleButton.setOnClickListener {
            oneTapClient.beginSignIn(signInRequest)
                .addOnSuccessListener(this) { result ->
                    try {
                        val intentSenderRequest = IntentSenderRequest.Builder(result.pendingIntent.intentSender).build()
                        activityResultLauncher.launch(intentSenderRequest)
                    } catch (e: IntentSender.SendIntentException) {
                        Log.e("oneTapSignIn", "Couldn't start One Tap UI: ${e.localizedMessage}")
                        errorText.text = "oneTapSignIn Couldn't start One Tap UI: ${e.localizedMessage}"
                    }
                }
                .addOnFailureListener(this) { e ->
                    // No Google Accounts found. Just continue presenting the signed-out UI.
                    Log.d("oneTapSignIn", e.localizedMessage)
                    errorText.text = "oneTapSignIn addOnFailureListener Couldn't start One Tap UI: ${e.localizedMessage}"
                }
        }
    }

    private fun handleSignInResult(result: ActivityResult) {
        try {
            val credential = oneTapClient.getSignInCredentialFromIntent(result.data)
            val idToken = credential.googleIdToken
            when {
                idToken != null -> {
                    // Got an ID token from Google. Use it to authenticate
                    // with your backend.
                    errorText.text = "Token Success GOt token $idToken"

                    Log.d("onActivityResult", "Got ID token.")
                }

                else -> {
                    // Shouldn't happen.
                    Log.d("onActivityResult", "No ID token!")
                    errorText.text = "No ID token!"
                }
            }
        } catch (e: ApiException) {
            Log.d("onActivityResult", "ApiException No ID token!")
            errorText.text = "Exception $e \n${e.localizedMessage} \n${e.message} \n ${e.cause} \n${e.stackTrace}!"
        }
    }
}
```

Ideally, I'd like to avoid Firebase, but either way, this is still not working. Is there a way to get more relevant debug information? Any ideas for solutions to test will be appreciated :)

Comment: have you added SHA1 and SHA256 key from Google Playstore to Firebase Console?

Comment: Only the SHA1, I removed SHA256. Also, I don't use Firebase (in the sense that the code we're using is from the Google documentation - not Firebase SDK), do you think it matters, like they're connected somehow?

Comment: @LearnPainLess added SHA256 and SHA1 for both upload and Google Play Store keys in Firebase...no luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was a 7-year-old forgotten project with some old email account owner in Google Cloud Console created and having the same SHA1 fingerprint OAuth Client ID setup.

The weirdest thing is though, how two different applications can be created in Google Play Console with the same app signing key! I hope this answer will help others think about non-technical blockers!

Comment: I had same issue.. thank you so much for this helpful answer to solve this painful issue...

Comment: @xplat I have an app a 10 years old white labelled apps. (100 apps with same keystore and SHA1) In this case what shall I need to do. My app is suddently failing the google login.

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy the new SHA-1 generated in play console and add it in firebase / GCP
[image]

Comment: Added SHA1, SHA256 for upload and Play Store keys in Firebase. I don't use the Firebase SDK but code from the on-tap Google sign-in documentation, do you think it is connected? I have tried with Firebase web OAuth Client ID and created a new one as well. No luck, same error.